# how to grab last part of url string in php

Tags: php, url

I am using a var `$dir` that gives me this path:

```
uploads/sha256/aaa
```

or

```
uploads/sha256/aaa/subaaa
```

or

```
uploads/sha256/aaa/subaaa/subsubaaa
```

The var `$UserID` produces the sha256

How can i grab the part **after** the sha256?

So grab only `aaa` or `aaa/subaaa` or `aaa/subaaa/subsubaaa`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why not write a regular expression, or use `explode`?

Comment: Regex that splits the string after 2 forward slashes seems the easiest way forward.

Comment: So `sha256` is a hash and not the literal string `sha256`. Please clarify your question and post realistic data for context so that volunteers are not confused.

Comment: It's not about splitting a string, there's user input and there's directories involved directly... There are caveats when designing this type of code and splitting a string doesn't quite cut this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that "sha256" is a user generated sha-256 hash value that will change for each user, you need to ignore it and focus on the fixed things in your URI, namely the slashes. One way around it is using regex:

```
$string = "uploads/sha256/aaa/subaaa/subsubaaa";
preg_match("/uploads\\/[^\\/]+\\/(.*)/", $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);

string(20) "aaa/subaaa/subsubaaa"
```

https://3v4l.org/QcPcl

Comment: This doesn't search for sha256

Comment: It doesn't need to. Because from what I understand, the sha256 is a variable that the user produces.

Comment: OP says: _How can i grab the part after the sha256?_

Comment: Ya, he also says _The var $UserID produces the sha256_, meaning the she256 is generated based on the value in the UserID. It's not the actual string "sha25", rather a sha256 hash.

Comment: Hmm. I think you are right.  I think the question's sample input is deceiving.

Comment: Ya, it's a little poorly written but let's see what OP says.

Comment: This is the only one that works for me! In all other answers, i dont get  the sha out of the string!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function. This will split the string at a specific delimiter. Then you can get the last value of the array this returns, which will be the string after $userId.

```
$dir = explode($UserID . '/', $dir);
echo $dir[1];
```

Comment: You can add the slash by concatenating the string, also no one used the $UserId variable that the OP mentioned. @mickmackusa

Answer (score 0):

explodes the string with `sha256/` and the second item in the array will be your required part.

```
   $x = explode('sha256/', "uploads/sha256/aaa/subaaa/subsubaaa");
   var_dump($x[1]);
```

Comment: updated, please check

Comment: It seems that `sha256` is not a literal string, but represents a substring that is a sha256 hash.  I have closed this duplicate question and it is likely to be deleted in time anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = explode("sha256/",$dir);//divides the string into array elements using 'sha256/' as breaking point note the trailing lash
$last = end($array);//grabs last element in array or in this case everything after sha256/
```

If you `trust` the $UserID then you could do this dynamicly like this:

```
$array = explode($UserID."/",$dir);//divides the string into array elements using $UserID as breaking point beware of ill input
$last = end($array);//grabs last element in array or in this case everything after sha256/
```

You should be aware of directory traversal and such exploits involving user input and directories. For example if the userid could be aaa or subaaa then you would have unpredictable behaviour.